# Using Powershell to call a function in .php webpage

Tags: javascript, powershell, function, developer-tools

I got into developer tools and found that function that I'm interested to know how it works. However, It seems like I can't trace to its source code, so I wish to call it externally.
Is it possible?
I was thinking to use the Invoke cmdlet, but I'm not sure how.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You've not really made it clear what you're trying to achieve with the call to the webpage, but this may do the trick.

```
$webresult = try {
    (Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing "http://www.mywebsite.com" -ErrorAction Stop)
} catch [System.Net.WebException] {
    Write-Verbose "An exception was caught: $($_.Exception.Message)"
    $_.Exception.Response
}
# Convert StatusCode to int, as the exception method doesn't return an INT (though the try does)
$StatusCodeInt = [int]$webresult.StatusCode
if ($StatusCodeInt -eq "200")
{
    write-host "Success"
}
```

I use it in quite a few scripts to either submit information to our intranet systems, or retrieve info from them for use in the scripts.

In addition to `$webresult.StatusCode` you can also retrieve other information from the result via `$webresult.StatusDescription` and $webresult.Content depending on your needs.